# Background-size: cover effect in HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm working on a newsletter for my photo community website. In the newsletter, I want to have a grid of images. Here's an unfinished rendering in an email client. As you can see it has problems, this is only to illustrate what I'm trying to build.

[image]

The image files in reality are about twice the resolution as shown in the email. Furthermore, they can be in any aspect ratio and orientation. What I would like to achieve:

- Force all images into 200 x 200px cells
- Do not distort the image, the aspect ratio must be maintained
- The cell must always be filled, both horizontally and vertically
- Background sizing should be centered
- Elements must be clickable, leading to that particular photo
- Should be robust and work in most popular email clients

In normal web technology (as opposed to HTML in email), this would be a matter of setting the image container to the fixed dimensions and using background-size: cover. I've learned about many HTML email limitations yet am trying to persist in finding one way or another.

Am I really on an impossible mission here?

What I've tried so far:

- Setting the image as a background on the a that wraps around the img tag. With some tweaks it can come to a reasonable result, yet centering is a problem and outlook.com does not show the images at all.
- Using normal img tags with "a" around it and trying to control max width and height on the image and its wrapper. Here too centering is the main problem

I really hope this can be done, one way or another (not that server-side resizing is not an option in my case).

Comment: Yeah - you're gonna have fun with this one. E-mail clients in 2014 are what web browsers were in 1998...

Comment: On one side you say it should `Force all images into 200 x 200px cells` and on the other side you say `Do not distort the image, the aspect ratio must be maintained`

Comment: @Mr.Alien in other words, he wants it to auto-crop...

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Not cropped, just adjusted to be fit within the cell, see the leftmost image in the bottom row.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Yup, but we can't expect email clients to behave as we are coding pages for chrome, anyways -OP use table, keep your emailer simple, thats all you can do

Comment: Can you show the code you have? we are not here to write it for you, only help

Comment: @Mr.Alien that's my point

Comment: On any web browser I would have said use jquery and manipualte the image, but with an email client... manually make thumbnails or do the manipulation server side before sending the mail.

Comment: 3 simple rules for email newslatters: - keep the layout simple; - use table layout; - pray :)

Comment: To clarify the cropping requirement: it should not be like the image in the bottom left corner: that one does not fill the cell. The cell must be filled, and the image must crop with its aspect ratio obtained. Exactly the same as "cover" would do in normal web technology.

Comment: @SamDenton I didn't ask to write the code for me. I clearly mentioned what I tried already. I'm looking for a hint on whether this is possible and what the approach would be, I can code it myself. There's no point for me to show code in an approach that simply does not work.

Comment: yea, there is, because your code could be almost right, but with a slight error we could fix

Answer (score 2):

Since this is on an email client, you can't use any scripting language. This mean that manipulating the image is impossible on the client side of thing.

You will have to manually create thumbnails for your pictures or make some code that creates thumbnail server side before creating the email.

This is as much as I can tell you without knowing how you are creating your emails.